# Crystal Report,VB.NET,ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can help to get rid of this error in the Production website.This error is showing when i click on the Reports(Crystal Report)

Error Message:

```
The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x80041016): The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +87
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +279

[Exception: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +341
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +869
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) +73
   Default3.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) +142
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +2069644
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +9
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +321
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +692
```

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you have to many Report instances open. We had the same issue using C#/Crystal Reprots trying to generate multi threaded reporting. You have to ensure that you close and dispose of the report properly once done with them.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I had the same thing happen to me awhile back.  You can temporarily fix the error by recycling your app pool, but you need to get in and close and dispose the report.